# Continue copying file

Tags: data-recovery, cp, file-copy, pv

I was copying a very big file and I accidentally stopped it. Can I resume copying data without need to delete copy and copy data again?

Command I used:

```
pv original.data > copy.data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continue with `dd`:

```
dd if=original.data of=copy.data ibs=512 obs=512 seek=NNN skip=NNN status=progress
```

You have to get byte count in the `copy.data`. Then replace `NNN`s with byte count divided by 512 (value set to `ibs` and `obs`).

Answer (score 4):

Using `rsync`:

```
rsync --append --progress original.data copy.data
```

With `--append`, `rsync` will assume that the data in `copy.data` is exactly the same as the data at the start of `original.data` and will just append the missing bit at the end.